# Components mapping in Railo

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, railo

I would like to put all of my CFC into /components folder and be able to call them from different places in application eg. from /forums/index.cfm.

How would I go about setting the mappings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Summary...

There are multiple ways to setup a mapping, and indeed two different types of mapping:

- A traditional mapping is created via the admin, and can be used anywhere within your CFML code. Railo supports per-context and per-server mappings of this type.
- There is also a per-application mapping, created either in your Application.cfc or via cfapplication tag, which can be used in *most* places, but are a runtime construct, so cannot be used at compile-time.

Also if you have global components, you might want to avoid using a mapping and simply tell Railo where your components are so you can access them directly.

### Creating a per-context mapping:

Go to the Railo Admin (i.e. `http://domain/railo-context/admin/web.cfm` ) and in the menu just over half way down you'll find "Archives & Resources", within which is "Mappings".

In the Virtual column enter `/components` and in the Resource column enter the absolute path to that directory (e.g. /home/user/public_html/components ), then press the save button.

You can also create a per-context mapping programmatically, using the [cfadmin tag](http://www.getrailo.org/index.cfm/documentation/cfadmin-doc/) with the action "updateMapping".

(Everything here also applies to per-server mappings, except using the Server Admin instead of the Web Admin. Per-server mappings are visible but read-only in the Web Admin interface.)

### Creating a per-application mapping:

To create a mapping only for a specific application, you can do this in Application.cfc

Simply create a variable called `this.mappings` which contains a struct of your virtual and resource values, for example:

```
This.Mappings = { '/components' : '/home/user/public_html/components' }
```

This mapping then will only apply for that application, allowing you to have the same mapping point to different locations for different applications.

Railo also allows per-application mappings to be created inside Application.cfm, by using the `cfapplication` tag - like so:

```
<cfset MappingStruct = { '/components' : '/home/user/public_html/components' } />
<cfapplication mappings=#MappingStruct# />
```

**Note:** application-level mappings have some restrictions, since they exist at runtime, but not at compile-time (so, for example, they can't be used for custom tag libraries, where the taglib attribute is evaluated when the template is compiled).

### Referencing a component with a mapping:

Either of these will enable you to do:

```
MyObj = createObject('component','components.NameOfFile').init()
```

Or:

```
MyObj = new components.NameOfFile()
```

(Note that you don't use `/component/nameoffile` like you might when otherwise using a mapping.)

### Global components without a mapping:

If you want to access the components globally *without* a mapping, goto the Components section (just below Mappings in the menu), and enter your absolute components path in the "Additional Resources" section. (Leave Trusted *unticked*.)

Then you can simply create your objects without the `components.` mapping being needed:

```
MyObj = new NameOfFile()
```

Answer (score 3):

You should define your mappings in `Application.cfc`.  Check out these related questions

[railo application.cfc this.mappings not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875621/railo-application-cfc-this-mappings-not-working)

[How can I include mappings into Application.cfc from external property file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551613/how-can-i-include-mappings-into-application-cfc-from-external-property-file)